# dnscrypt-proxy - check what resolver I am using

Tags: dns, dnscrypt-proxy

I have installed `dnscrypt-proxy` on my ubuntu 14.04.

Now I'd like to check what resolver I am using. 
I know that the default configuration uses OpenDNS server, but I'd like to know what server it's using among those listed in the default list: https://github.com/jedisct1/dnscrypt-proxy/blob/master/dnscrypt-resolvers.csv.
How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to check which resolver you are actually using is to visit this website.

https://dnsleaktest.com/

Further explanations are in a webupd8.com article :

[Encrypt DNS Traffic In Ubuntu With DNSCrypt [Ubuntu PPA]](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/encrypt-dns-traffic-in-ubuntu-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [ipleak.net](http://ipleak.net) and your current DNS server(s) IP addresses will be displayed. Than you can cross referance the IP with the IP's in the resolvers.csv file. You can also go to [opendns.com/welcome](https://www.opendns.com/welcome/) and find out if you are indeed using they're nameservers or not.

Another way would be to install wireshark, and start capturing packets. You will see every single packet going through your system. If are using dncrypt without a dns cache, such as dnsmasq or unbound, you will be able to see the IP address of the nameserver, however you should not be able to see the query itself, because it's encrypted.

Of course, there are tools such as dig and whois that you can use to debug DNS related issues as well. Good luck.